# Why is running node.js on port 80 might not be safe?

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm aware that nodejs can run on the port 80 by :

- setting up a proxy with apache/nginx
- setting up a port redirection with an iptables rule
- making express listen on port 80 within the app

The first option isn't the easiest and require more dependencies then I need. The second one could be working but on my OpenVZ VPS it won't (and I can't compile a custom linux kernel).

I needed to handle some sub-domains too, and after reading this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js), I tried the third solution.
It's perfectly working and very easy to perform.

I was wondering if there might be some security issues while running nodejs directly on the 80 port ? How may I fix/found these ?

I wanted to use pm2 to handle the processes and it might run [not as root](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/92?source=c) ([Goodbye node-forever hello pm2](http://devo.ps/blog/2013/06/26/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2.html)).

Comment: Why would it be less safe than on another port ?

Comment: @dystroy: It might be less safe than proxying through nginx, in case someone finds a vulnerability in Node's HTTP parser.

Comment: @dystroy Good question so running it with a proxy, an iptable or directly on port 80 'll lead to the same security issues ?

Comment: If your firewall doesn't mask the original port, that's certain. If it does and you use a proxy **and** there's a vulnerability in Node's http parser that's masked by a proxy, then this solution might be faster. But I seriously doubt it and I would need a link to that vulnerability before I consider such a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first option isn't the easiest and require more dependencies then I need

Please review [why should one use a http server in front of a framework web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372297/why-should-one-use-a-http-server-in-front-of-a-framework-web-server/13372425#13372425) for the many valid reasons **you should in fact do it this way**.

> setting up a port redirection with an iptables rule

This is probably better than directly having your node process listen on port 80, although I haven't seen this type of configuration used in production.

> making express listen on port 80 within the app

This is functionally a poor choice because you don't get the benefits outlined in the linked answer above, however, from a strictly security standpoint, the key thing to remember is **you must not run your node process as root**, which would be a horrendous security problem. You must be root to bind to port 80 because that's a rule of unix, but you can and must change to a less-privileged user immediately after binding to that port.

Comment: I'm using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) and I think they're working on running it as a user.
Thanks for the link very interesting!

Comment: It's a very fine line between port redirection and using a redirecting proxy like [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). As you point out, running as `root` is almost always a Very Bad Idea.