# NodeJS Production server with pm2 works but have some error

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 to launch my NodeJS/Angular application in production mode. Im running the application on port 80 and have given premissions to the user by: `sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/local/bin/node`. **The website works** but I get some kind of access error in the logs:

```
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/home/nodeuser/Disri/dist/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:533:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nodeuser/Disri/dist/server.js:44:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
```

**What could cause this error?**

Comment: Don't run on 80 but add nginx with an upstream proxy in front of your nodejs app that listen's on another port.

Comment: I don't want nginx, it runs on port 80 just fine after the permission modification.

Comment: You should use nginx or apache on top of the nodejs app.

Comment: why? I use pm2 which also have a load balancer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409749/why-is-running-node-js-on-port-80-might-not-be-safe read the answer link, make some research.

Comment: im not running the application as root as far as i know:/ But I will test nginx proxy just to make sure there is no problem. Thanks